# Azure Logic Apps Trigger not fired

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am testing Azure Logic apps for a used case where I want to parse new tweets and write them to SQL. The flow works seamlessly.
But the problem is that although I have selected 1 sec for "How often do you want to check for items?" field, it seems triggers are not fired automatically. I have to press Run Trigger to to capture new tweets.
Is there any idea how to overcome this problem?
Thank you

Comment: Is it possible to share the workflow design? So that we will get a better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

The "How often do you want to check for items" means the trigger will check if a new tweet was posted every 1 second but not run every 1 second. If the problem is not caused by misunderstanding, please check if any of the following limits are not met:
[image]

You can find more information on this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/twitterconnector/).

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. But still can not understand the concept. When I run the trigger in design mode, the flow runs and checks if new tweets are posted and captures the tweets I sent for testing purposes, however after a while run button becomes visible again and trigger is not shot. Hence, i can not see the tweets I posted after this time interval. Also I am getting following error "Workflow run timed out because the starting action was not performed. Please try again."

Comment: Hi @emkay, I'm a little confused about your question. You mentioned you can't see the tweets you posted after the time interval, but it just because you run it manually in design mode. If you let it triggered automatically(for example 10 seconds), it will check every 10 seconds and if capture a new tweet, it will be triggered. If misunderstand your question, please let me know. Or you can provide some screenshots to state your question more clearly.